# Pyspark Dataframe read from S3 with variable path with current date

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I wanna read a partition from S3 with aws spark job with current date and current hour. Is it possible this path set with current_date() and hour(current_timestamp())function.

[image: current_date -> for ex 2022-09-07, current_hour -> for ex 18]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors, maybe you can elaborate more on your approach.
If you want to provide the value to current_date and current_hours in your above code then import datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now() --> 2022-10-01 07:58:56.550604
```

and provide value to each of the variables.

If you want to read the data in your S3 partitioned based on date, current_date etc., then run the glue job with enabled job bookmarks option which will read only newly added data from S3.

Comment: I'm trying to read data and filter according to some conditions, and repartition with different columns and write another bucket on S3. I'm using glue spark job. And I'm reading data with spark.read.parquet("s3 path") in a dataframe. I dont want to read all data every time. Data is being written by partitioned by current date and hour. It is enough to read last hour data. I think it may be more efficient and less cost.